# How to recreate the logo of my University

Tags: graphics, titles, logos

I am trying to recreate the logo text part of the logo of my University. What I want to reproduce is just the text part. I know the font is Helvetica Neue bold.

[image]

In particular, I would like to leave some space on the top and the left like it is done in this logo, in order to insert it in my thesis. How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't it be much easier to simply create the image in the image manipulation program of your choice, and insert the resulting image? I am not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve, do you want to remove the seal and the Latin byline?

Comment: You can create horizontal space with `\hspace{2mm}` or `\hspace*{2mm}` for example, and vertical space with `\vspace{5mm}` or `\\[5mm]`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.